# Open new window without URL. PHP/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, onclick

The problem currently:
I have a website that we are moving to a mobile application so I have put the website inside an IFrame (this has to be done not my choice). However when you click a certain link on the website (ON MOBILE) it will take you to a third party website or download page still inside the original Iframe. This is where the problem arises when you are on that third party website or download page there is no back button for mobile users (ios specifically).

My Ideas:
One way to fix this problem would be if the button is clicked the contents open up in a new window outside of the original Iframe on mobile.

Once the buy now button is clicked you will get directed to the third party website link.

This buttons code is not written in simple html or css though so there is no basic url set to the button. This means the window.open function will not work since a url is required and putting "_blank" attribute inside the php variable did not work either. Since my button is in a PHP variable called button that triggers a dynamic url through a CMS I am quite lost and not sure if this can be done.

What I want to happen is a new window to open with the third party website outside of the IFrame.

My PHP button

```php
$button .= "<button class=\"btn btn-product-box get-coupon-btn deal-download ".$extraClass."\" onclick=\"myFunction()" . "\" data-action=\"".$purchaseAction."\">".$text."</button>";
```

I believe that the data-action attribute which holds the value $purchaseAction is related to the urls or links

I have added an onclick function to the button called myFunction which is a java script function that I am trying to write to trigger the button to open its contents in a new window.

My onclick function

```
function myFunction() {
                        document.getElementsByClassName('get-coupon-btn');
                        console.log("clicked myFunction");
                        var jsvar = '<?=$purchaseMethod?>';
                        console.log(jsvar);
                    }
```

I believe that `$purchaseAction` holds the URLs to the third party websites. But since they are grabbed from a CMS through twig programming language I do not have the http links for the sites and the button will trigger a different website depending on what button is clicked.

Here is more of the code

```
$purchaseMethods = $purchasable->purchaseMethods->orderBy(new Expression("Field(`typeId`, 32,18,19,31,17)"))->all();
//        Log::error_log($purchasable->purchaseMethods->orderBy(new Expression("Field(`typeId`, 32,18,19,31,17)"))->getRawSql());
//        $totalBtn = 0;
        if(empty($purchaseMethods)){
            $text = "REPORT ERROR";
            if($short){
                $text = "ERROR";
            }
            $button = "<a href=\"mailto:".GlobalSet::find()->handle("businessInformation")->one()->email."?subject=Enquiry for Product '".$product->title."'&body=Hi, I saw this product at '". $product->uri. "' %0A%0AWrite Your Request Here.....%0A%0A\" class=\"btn btn-product-box\">".$text."</a>";
        }
        foreach($purchaseMethods as $loopIndex => $purchaseMethod){
            switch ($purchaseMethod->type){
                case "printMaterial":
                    $purchaseAction = $purchaseMethod->image->count() != 0? $purchaseMethod->image->one()->url : null;
                    $text = "GET COUPON";
                    if($short){
                        $text = "GET";
                    }
                    //$button .= "<button class=\"btn btn-product-box get-coupon-btn deal-download ".$extraClass."\" data-action=\"".$purchaseAction."\">".$text."</button>";
                    $button .= "<button class=\"btn btn-product-box get-coupon-btn deal-download ".$extraClass."\" onclick=\"myFunction()"."\" target=\"_blank" ."\" data-action=\"".$purchaseAction."\">".$text."</button>";
                    ?>
                    <script>
                    //const { shell } = require('electron');
                    //var aHref = document.querySelector('#aHref');

                    function myFunction() {
                        document.getElementsByClassName('get-coupon-btn');
                        console.log("clicked myFunction");
                        //var jsvar = '<?=$purchaseMethod?>';
                        //console.log(jsvar);
                    }
                    </script>
```

Is there any way I can get the button to open its contents in a new window without using `window.open` or `_blank` since they both require urls?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the HTML, PHP and your Javascript. Images of code are not helpful. What is the content of the variable `$purchaseAction`?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling myFunction(), when the button is clicked in Iframe.

Inside myFunction, you can open the URL using the following code which will open URL in a new tab outside Iframe

```
window.open(href, '_blank');
```

Here href is URL which you are grabbing from HTML

Comment: Yes this would work but I do not have a url or href or link in my html code. This is the problem since the links are not given and created dynamically through the CMS.

Comment: I saw the code in image yesterday, which is getting URL dynamically using PHP and dumping into HTML.. Then you are grabbing it using JS (href variable).  you can use it with window.open. Am i missing something?